# Crystal Reports: Conditional Font Formatting

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I've been trying in vain to get conditional formatting working in this report.

I select the field, right click, Format Field and then I click the X+1 button to right of colour.

I then enter this:

`if{@col_1_calc} < 0 then crRed else crYellow`

It doesnt seem to do anything at all.  The text is all black.  If I right click, format field and select 'Blue' from the immediate options, The text is blue.

It seems as if the conditional formats are just, turned off.  If I replace the above format with just 'crYellow', still nothing.

Any suggestions for trouble shooting?

Comment: Try parens instead of curly braces. I think that's the only problem. Oh wait, I think the parens need to wrap the entire expression including the zero.

Comment: @shawnt00 can you give an example? why would {} be a problem?

Comment: Well `{}` is used for referring to fields. I can't remember if Crystal expression syntax requires the parens but if it does then you need to include the whole expression.

Comment: @shawnt00 well, all the examples online are identical as far as i can see to my one above.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Let me check. I haven't written this stuff in many years.

Comment: Looks like you're right about it. And that explains why you didn't report a syntax error. What about null values? Are you sure your formula evaluates to a real value?

Comment: I agree that the constant value (crYellow) should have worked.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using conditional formatting through the other dialog. I think it overrides formulas.

Comment: Crystal used to be really screwy back 15 years ago. I'm searching my memory banks to try and help. Honestly I you might have luck by deleting and recreating the whole object. Or try duplicating the behavior in a brand new report.

Comment: @shawnt00, Thanks for all the answers :) What is the other dialog that does conditional formatting? As I was going to sleep I thought I should try the highlighting expert, and that seems to have done it :)

Comment: Have you placed the formula in design part of the report? if yes then where did you place the formula and when it is getting evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer, but theres no other way i couldhave uploaded a screenshot. Not sure how you are applying color to the field. This is how I would, Right Click on Field and use the Font tab. as below. I may be using a different version of crystal than you.[image]